# Using Jquery to change the colour of a text link when rolling over a related image

Tags: jquery, css

A client of mine has given me an interesting website to code. Basically, there's a load of projects. 
The project names and brief descriptions are listed in a left-hand column. Each project has an image associated with it, placed in the right-hand column.
Each image has a colour overlayed - when you roll over the image, the overlay is removed, showing the image underneath in its natural colours. (This was achieved with the kind help of someone else on this forum, using Jquery).

What the client now wants to do is to change the colour of the project's text link when the user rolls over the image.
E.g. When the user rolls over the 'Atlantic Yarns' image, the client wants the 'Atlantic Yarns' text link on the right to rollover in blue. The client also wants it to work the other way - when the user rolls over the text link, the overlay is removed from the image.
I'm at a loss of how to do this, not even sure it can be done but the client is insisting!
Please can anyone help?

Demo site is here: http://dob.ck-services.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a > img').hover(function() {
    var a = $(this).closest('a');
    $('a[href="' + a.attr('href') + '"]').not(a).addClass('hover');
}, function() {
    var a = $(this).closest('a');
    $('a[href="' + a.attr('href') + '"]').not(a).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Then you just need to add a CSS rule for `a.hover` that applies the same styles as 
`a:hover`, e.g.:

```
a:hover, a.hover {
    color: #0f0;
}
```

Comment: Hi ThiefMaster,
Thanks for this, I've installed it but have been unable to make it work. Am I right in thinking that it finds the nearest <a> tag and adds a class="hover" to it? If so it probably won't work as it's not always the nearest <a> tag that needs to change, thanks to the client's design. Have you any further ideas?

Comment: Nope, it takes the href from the nearest (in your case: parent) `a` tag and takes another a tag with *exactly the same* href and adds the class to this one. I tested it via firebug console on your site and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
jQuery("#right_col").children().hover(
function(){//hover over
  var $this = jQuery(this);
  var id = $this.attr("id");
  jQuery("#" + id + "_desc").find("a").addClass("projectHover");
  $this.find(".blueoverlay").hide();
}, function(){//hover out
  var $this = jQuery(this);
  var id = $this.attr("id");
  jQuery("#" + id + "_desc").find("a").removeClass("projectHover");
  $this.find(".blueoverlay").show();
});
```

This code has hover effect for image also, which you are already doing. So, remove the other code.

NOTE: Please add below class to your CSS.

```
.projectHover{color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the similarity in IDs, could you do something like this?

```
$('#right_col a img').hover(function(){
    $parentname = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
    $('#'+$parentname+'_desc a').toggleClass('hover');
});

$('#left_col h2 a').mouseover(function(){
    $parentname = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
    $imgname = $parentname.replace(/_desc/i,'');
    $('#' + $imgname).mouseover();
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('#' + $imgname).mouseout();
});
```

And then add the CSS to the .hover class as mentioned above, like this?

```
#project1_desc a:hover, #project1_desc a.hover {
  color: #4F99FF;
}
```